# Excel will not let me delete a row

Tags: excel

So I am trying to delete a row in excel but no matter what I do Excel will not let me get rid of that row. I tried highlighting the entire row and hitting 'Delete' on my keyboard but that just renamed all the row values to generic names like 'Column 1' and 'Column 2' and so on.

Any suggestion to how I can delete this row?

EDIT: Nevermind, I realized that the problem was that the row I was trying to edit was an header row

Comment: highlight row, hit ctrl - minus?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Excel?

Comment: When asking a question about a ListObject Table (aka *structured table*), it is best to specify that the problem involves a ListObject Table. There are special concerns with ListObject Tables. In your case, it was going to Table Tools ► Design ► Table Style Options and unchecking **Header Row**.

Comment: Please add the resolution as an answer even though you solved it yourself. I had the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I realized that the problem was that the row I was trying to edit was an header row

Answer (score 10):

In Microsoft Excel 2016 highlight the row, click the Design tab, uncheck "Header Row" above the Table Styles Options.

Comment: In my case the tab was called "Table Design"

Comment: Don't you love how Microsoft changes the names of things all the time!

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the row, right-click the row header, and select delete. Alternately, try typing Ctrl minus.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes along this way I had the same issue.  I could delete lines after the main table, which included sum() formulae, but not in it, very strange.  A couple of posts I saw mentioned pressing F5 ( goto ) -> Special... and then choosing Objects to see if there was something weird in there.  I chose last cell and that took me to a row I1048253 in which there was a sum starting at line 3 and included the table's sums.  Deleting that, or changing the start row to just under the table, allowed me to delete the rows.